# How to show small icon with notification content text Like Whatsapp do?

Tags: android, android-notifications, whatsapp

I have been searching this from a long time but i didnt find any answer ,Anyone can help ?

Image for Reference attached 
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9BoUL.jpg)
I want to to achieve this

Comment: you can use totally custom notification layout

Comment: Is there any way you know so that i can achieve using default notifications?

Comment: I don't say there is no such way, but I don't know it.

Comment: Please add the XML layout for your notification

Comment: I dont want to use custom notification , I need to integrate it with default notifications .

Comment: have you got the solution?

Comment: Unfortunately not , I implemented it using custom xml layout